# Php: how to create variables on the fly

Tags: php, string, variables

I am testing this sample of php code and I wonder why isn't giving the same result:

```
Head Title
. $theTitle .
```

instead of:

```
Head Title
Head Title
```

```
 $theTitle = "Head Title";
 define( "TEMPLATE", "<div class=\"well\">{{theTitle}}</div>");
 $Template = str_replace("{{", '" . $', TEMPLATE);
 $Template = str_replace("}}", ' . "', $Template);
 echo $theTitle;
 echo $Template;
```

How to achieve it?
Regards,
Marco

Comment: Since you are using str_replace, why not just `"{{theTitle}}"` to `$theTitle`. No need to make it complex

Comment: Thank you @Andreas but I've found the solution that I needed. I used Eval() and it works 
            eval("\$str = \"$additionalTemplate\";");

Comment: The above sample of code is just a sample: I know that it's much better to use use $theFile instead of {{theTitle}} but all the variables definded in TEMPLATE constant arent' defined yet, in actual code.

Comment: If your sample is not good enough to explain what you want/need/have problems with then don't post your question yet. Think, rewrite and make sure the question explains what the problem is. And I hope you are not using eval on user input

Comment: Improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

Use str_replace and replace `"{{theTitle}}"` with `$theTitle`.

```
$Template = str_replace("{{theTitle}}", $theTitle, TEMPLATE);
```